# Did not receive a second Out of Office reply

Tags: email

I sent out some documents of the "very important" kind to my college during the holiday.  I received a confirmation email for the first one sent but not the second or the third. I sent all emails on the same night - the first at around 8:50pm,  the second at 11:55pm and the third around 11:59pm. Yes, it was due at midnight... and yeah, I'm a super procrastinator...

My question is - were the last two received? Would the auto-reply system not bother sending me a second confirmation if it was sent in the same day?

Thanks guys! I know this is super simple but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere and cant contact the department to check if the emails were received...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, only one OOO Reply is sent to each sender (not each message).

> [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157961)
>   The Out of Office Assistant sends an automatic reply to notify users who send you messages that you are away from the office. **Your reply is only sent once to a message sender. The count is reset when you toggle the Out of Office Assistant.** Microsoft Exchange clears its internal "sent to" list when you disable the Out of Office Assistant. 
>   If you would like to have a reply sent for every message, use Rules instead of the Out of Office Assistant.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I'm so digitally hugging your face right now! :-)